# ubuntu change ethernet driver for atheros ar8132 to enable jumbo frames

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I would like to enable jumbo frames on my ethernet card(atheros ar8132). According to this page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man4/alc.4freebsd.html the alc driver supports jumbo frames. So I would like to enable the alc driver on my computer. How will I do that? Thank you.

Comment: What is your current driver? `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Hello and thank you!!! This is the response 

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8132 Fast Ethernet [1969:1062] (rev c0)
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7592]
        Kernel driver in use: atl1c

Comment: Did you try to use MTU? `sudo iw link set eth0 mtu 4000` or whatever? Didn't it work?

Comment: the command that you gave me is wrong. But when I use sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 4000, I get SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument

Comment: so, do you know a way to change the driver?

Comment: Do I know a way to use a BSD driver that doesn't even exist in Ubuntu as far as I can tell? No, I'm afraid not. There may be some clue here: ttps://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/howto-optimize-gigabit-networking-in-linux/

Comment: I am sorry, I thought that the driver is available for ubuntu because the article is written at "ubuntu manpages"

Comment: Is there another way, to enable jumbo frames? The link that you provided isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The link I gave has a typo; I apologize.

The idea is to find the highest mtu that your ethernet card, driver and router can manage. Please try:

```
ping -c3 -s 1550 -M do 8.8.8.8
```

Keep increasing the mtu until you see: `Message too long, mtu=XXX` The resultant number can be set:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu XXX
```

Of course, substitute your interface if not `eth0`. Set it permanently in Network Manager or `/etc/network/interfaces`, whichever you use to configure your ethernet.